# login user should access only topic which user has posted

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

User should get only his/her topics but user is getting all users topic in html.

User can post topic and in post user can see list of topic. User should see only user topics but all user topic is being seen. What would be the procedure to get only user topic, for example:

- ram creates topic as

  - laptop
  - mobile
  - tv
- shyam creates topic as

  - furniture
  - food

while creating post ram should get only topic option as laptop,mobile,tv but he is getting all option including shyam topic also. Following are the codes

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="alltopic")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def createPost(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect("postlist")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "createpost.html", context)
```

and html

```
<div class="container">
  <form  method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.as_p}}
     <button type="submit" >submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your `PostForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the `QuerySet` of the `Topic`s in your `PostForm`:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    # …
    
    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['topic'].queryset = Topic.objects.filter(user=user)
```

and then pass the user to the constructor of the form:

```
def createPost(request):
    form = PostForm(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('postlist')
    context={
    'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'createpost.html',context)
```

Comment: I am getting error in constructor
def __init__(self, *args, user=None.queryset = Topic.objects.filter(user=user)
                                                                        (^) in between querset and Topic
like this error is showing

Comment: @BonishThapa: sorry, I made a typo in the code formating. Fixed.